# HTTP API calls receiving no response on Xamarin Android Debug mode

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-emulator

Basically whenever I select debug configuration on Android in Visual Studio, None of the API calls work. They are sent but there is never any response. Internet is working as I can log in plus see it in the browser and the API calls work when I switch to iOS on debug configuration. They are working on release configuration on Android as well.

Properties for both of them.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
<DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>    
<DebugType>full</DebugType>    
<Optimize>false</Optimize>    
<OutputPath>bin\Debug</OutputPath>    
<DefineConstants>DEBUG;</DefineConstants>    
<ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>    
<WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>    
<AndroidUseAapt2>true</AndroidUseAapt2>    
<AndroidDexTool>d8</AndroidDexTool>    
<AndroidSupportedAbis>arm64-v8a;armeabi-v7a</AndroidSupportedAbis>    
<AndroidHttpClientHandlerType>Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler</AndroidHttpClientHandlerType>    
<AndroidPackageFormat>apk</AndroidPackageFormat>    
<AndroidEnableProfiledAot>true</AndroidEnableProfiledAot>    
<AndroidLinkMode>None</AndroidLinkMode>  
</PropertyGroup>  

<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">    
<DebugSymbols>false</DebugSymbols>    
<DebugType>none</DebugType>    
<Optimize>true</Optimize>     
<AndroidPackageFormat>aab</AndroidPackageFormat>    
<AndroidDexTool>d8</AndroidDexTool>    
<AndroidUseAapt2>true</AndroidUseAapt2>    
<OutputPath>bin\Release</OutputPath>    
<ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>    
<WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>    
<AndroidManagedSymbols>true</AndroidManagedSymbols>    
<AndroidUseSharedRuntime>false</AndroidUseSharedRuntime>    
<AndroidSupportedAbis>armeabi-v7a;arm64-v8a</AndroidSupportedAbis>    
<AndroidHttpClientHandlerType>Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler</AndroidHttpClientHandlerType>  
</PropertyGroup>
```

Some more information, I am using Visual Studio For Mac plus the Android SDK being targeted is 33. The API calls (SendAsync) are working as intended on Android Release and iOS Debug/Release

Comment: Is there any log about this problem?

Comment: No, the API request in sent but it keeps waiting and the request never gets a response

Comment: You can debug your code step by step, and there should be clues to find errors.